# Is there a convex polyhedron with product of numbers of faces, vertices and edges equal to $3375$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polyhedra

Is there a convex polyhedron with product of numbers of faces, vertices and edges equal to $3375$?

We are told that: $|E| \cdot |V| \cdot |F| = 3375$. From that we get $|E| = \frac{3375}{|V| \cdot |F|}$

Then I tried to use Eulers equation: $|F| + |V| = |E| + 2 \implies |F| + |V| = \frac{3375}{|V| \cdot |F|} + 2 \iff |V| \cdot |F|^2 + |V|^2 \cdot |F| = 3375 + 2|V| \cdot |F|$

And so I get:

$$|V| \cdot |F|^2 - 2|V| \cdot |F| + |V|^2 \cdot |F|  = 3375$$

I know that from steinitz theorem, for convex polyhedron to exist it is necessary that:

- $|F| + |V| = |E| + 2$ (eulers equation)
- $3|V| \leq 2|E|$
- $3|F| \leq 2|E|$

So I tried to use those, but I don't know how / don't konw if that's the right direction.

*Also, the number $3375$ looks 'nice' in a way - it can be divided many times by $5$. Maybe there is some use in that.

Comment: Yes, indeed we have $3375=3^3\cdot 5^3$. So only finitely many decompositions in a product of integers $abc=3375$ with $c=a-b+2$ and so on. Did you try to rewrite this and solve in positive integers?

Comment: The closest product you can get with those constraints is 3450, with E=23 and either (F=10, V=15) or its dual (F=15, V=10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint :**
Consider the parity of the numbers $|E|, |V|, |F|$ from
$$|E| \cdot |V| \cdot |F| = 3375 \quad \text{and} \quad |F| + |V| = |E| + 2$$

Comment: Ohhh, I wouldn't think about it at all! That's briliant. We from the equation on the LHS that all $3$ numbers ($|E|, |V|, |F|$) have to be odd since $3375$ is odd. Then on the equation on the RHS we see that $|F| + |V| - |E$ has to be an even number - since $2$ is even. $|F| + |V| - |E$ can't be an even number if all three of those numbers are odd. So, to sum up - there's not a single convex polyhedron with product of numbers of faces, vertices and edges equal to $3375$. Is that correct? @MyMolecules

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly correct! Whenever one encounters an equation with integer solutions, it is basic habit to check parity, remainders et cetera which could simplify the problem a lot.